# Return by reference swift

Tags: swift

Take the following example:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar: Int = 0
}

func getBar (forFoo foo: Foo) -> Int {
    return foo.bar
}

let foo = Foo()
var bar = getBar(forFoo: foo)
bar = 1
print("foo.bar: \(foo.bar)")
```

In `getBar`, I would like to be able to return a *reference* to `foo.bar` so that when I modify `bar` it *changes* the value of `foo.bar` not just `bar`

How do I do this?

Comment: An int is a struct so it’s not a reference type but NSNumber is

Comment: You can't.  If you want a reference, you have to use a reference type.  Best you could do would be to use a wrapper class like NSNumber instead.

Comment: Okay thanks. Is there no way to do this with structs as well?

Comment: No, structs are value types.  If one of the struct's properties is a class though, you can still get a reference to it.  But there's no way to do it without using a class at some point.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with it a little, it looks like `NSNumber` doesn't actually do what you want either, so you'd need to write your own custom wrapper.  For example:

```
struct Foo {
    let bar = IntWrapper(0)
}

class IntWrapper {
    var value: Int
    init (_ value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}    

func getBar (forFoo foo: Foo) -> IntWrapper {
    return foo.bar
}

let foo = Foo()
let bar = getBar(forFoo: foo)
bar.value = 1
print("foo.bar: \(foo.bar.value)") // prints 1
```

Note that I changed some of the `var`s to `let` since you only need to use `var` on reference types if you're changing the reference itself.